# Does redux form field warnings work in Admin on rest inputs?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am referring to the below documentation,

> **Tip:** The props you pass to `<SimpleForm>` and `<TabbedForm>` end up as
>   reduxForm() parameters. This means that, in addition to validate, you
>   can also pass warn or asyncValidate functions. Read the reduxForm()
>   documentation for details.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CreateEdit.html#validation

I tried defining `warn` property at the field level as well as at the form level, but warning text doesn't get displayed. However, I do see the `warning` property being set correctly in the `meta` property of that field.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Thanks

Example (Field level):

```
const isTest = val => (val === "TEST" ? "Really, TEST?" : undefined);

const PeersCreateEditInputs = (
  <SimpleForm>
    <TextInput source="ln" label="Name" validate={[required]} warn={isTest} />
....
```

Example (Form level):

```
const isTest = values => {
  const warnings = {};
  if (values.ln === "TEST") {
    warnings.ln = "Hmm, still TEST?";
  }
  return warnings;
};

const PeersCreateEditInputs = (
  <SimpleForm warn={isTest}>
    <TextInput source="ln" label="Name" validate={[required]} />
...
```

Comment: Can you share your form code ?

Comment: Updated the question with code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, the warning is passed but not displayed. I opened an issue on the `admin-on-rest` repository: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/1000